# Analog INPUT_PULLUP for resistive sensors?

Tags: analogread, photoresistor

Can you use the internal pull-up on an ADC pin? Is it correct usage? Example of hardware usage would be a cadmium photocell between *Ax* and *GND*. Software is the same, except declaring *Ax* as INPUT_PULLUP instead of INPUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you use the internal pull-up on an ADC pin?

Yes.

> Is it correct usage?

No. The exact pullup resistance varies from pin to pin and chip to chip, so depending on it for the high side is problematic at best.

Ideally you should be disabling the digital circuitry on an analog input entirely by writing to the `DIDR0` and `DIDR1` registers appropriately.

Comment: There is the convenience factor, though